# Live site blank in frontend or keep on loading and never load

Tags: cache, frontend, cookie

I am facing Strangest Problem ever in magento. we are using 1.9.0 version.

from last 2 months, our live site is "blank" or "keep on loading" for used browsers. Means in this browser we visited the site lot of times.

in some browsers, its working fine. in some showing blank.

but **backend** is working fine in all browsers.

we are facing problem in **chrome, mozilla , opera** and all other browsers.

1)If we clear the browser history[cache and cookies], than its working.

2)If we open the same site in private window , its working.

3)If we open the site in freshly installed browsers, its working for some time. again blank after we used the site.

4)If we clear the var/session folder, than it will start to work for all browsers for some time. again site blank.

5)sometimes, site will be keep on loading and it will never load....

I checked **system.log & exception.log** . but seems there are no errors related to this. we are using **https for secure** pages. even we have live **Andriod app** for this site. sometimes we will get Fatal errors  :

```
**Fatal error**: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 85 bytes) in /lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php or lib/Varien/Object.php or /lib/Varien/Db/Select.php or app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
```

we set memory_limit = 1512 Mb in php.ini

in **.htaccess** we have following files.

php_value memory_limit 1512M
php_value max_execution_time 18000

we uncommented this :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

but no error displaying in frontend. This is **apache error** log :

child pid 23845 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2

Really struggling to solve this problem. Is this problem related to our code or is this problem related to server side ?

is browser cookie is the main problem ? If so what need to do to solve this cookie problem for all browsers. why its started working once we clear session folder?

we face these issues when browsing our site.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: is it possible that its a cookie issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491819/magento-admin-login-not-working-in-chrome-but-works-fine-for-firefox

Comment: the link i pasted is for backend but the frontend may have a cookie issue also...it may be due to the lifetime of the cookie and the timestamp of the server is off

Comment: @pzirkind in our case backend is fine for all browsers. than is we have to increase the lifetime of cookie through code? and i did't got about timestamp of the server is off. is we have to make it on?

Comment: @Babby in Magento sometimes if the server does not have correct timestamp it will generate a cookie that expires before current date, so when customer reloads the site and magento checks the cookie its invalid

Comment: @pzirkind Is there any possibility that apache error posted in question or timestamp may be the reason for this blank page?

Comment: no, but there might be more than issue going on, the timestamp issue could help explain the browser behaviour - not the apache error

Comment: can you post name of site? i'll take a quick look

Comment: As you said, i followed the answer in this link : app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php i comment out session cookie paramas. now i am getting fatal error in site.

Comment: this is the exact replica of our site : http://videomergerapp.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33016/discussion-between-pzirkind-and-baby-in-magento).

Comment: By any chance, do you have a redirect depending on language or something implemented? Or do you have a staging website on a subdomain  `dev.yourdomain.com/`?

Comment: @Marius We did't implemeted those kind of things. Unfortunately We dont have staging website on domain.

Comment: Also, duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94970/browser-cookies-are-killing-our-live-site?lq=1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First enable Developer mode in your `.htaccess` file, add the following at the end of the file:

`SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"`

Next edit `index.php` and uncomment the line:

`#ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Line referenced:

- https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/magento-1.9/index.php#L73

Next login via SSH and look for a core dump file under `/tmp` as the segment fault error mentioned.  Sometimes it can also be in the root `/` or in the root directory of the site itself for example: `/var/www/html/videomergerapp/`.

If you are unable to locate any core dump files, you may want to add some additional directives to PHP/Apache.

Take a look here:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/470407/how-to-get-a-core-dump-from-apache-when-segfaulting
- http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/configure-apache-web-server-for-core-dump.html

Once you have the core dump file(s), you can use `gdb` (if `--enable-debug`) was used when PHP was configured.  You can make this determination by issuing the following from the Command Line:

`php -i | grep debug` or simply creating a php script file in your webserver root with: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` in its contents and view the file via web browser to see the PHP configuration values.

- https://bugs.php.net/bugs-generating-backtrace.php

If it was not enabled, then you won't be able to get a full backtrace into PHP itself but only higher level system calls and/or apache backtrace:

If you do have access to the core dump file issuing something like the following will give you a backtrace to help find the point of failure:

`gdb /usr/local/apache2/bin/httpd /tmp/core.2027`

---

If you are only experiencing the random issues on the frontend and never the backend, then most signs point to a possible issue with your template coding.  Once you experience the blank pages (and/or error displays if you have enabled developer mode and error display).  Login to your admin and disable all caches and flush all caches and cache storages.

Then going into `app/etc/local.xml` and set the disable local modules to true.

`<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>`

This will disable the auto loader from loading any modules in `app/code/local`.

To disable community modules it is easiest to go through each of your modules definition files found in `app/etc/modules` and disabling by setting the active node to false like so:

`<active>false</active>`

This way you can help rule out if a 3rd party module is causing the source of the issue by process of elimination.  NOTE: You can not `disable_local_modules` and simply go through all of your **NON-CORE** modules (anything Mage_* ignore!).

If there is still issues then I would attempt a default template package temporarily by going to System > Design and defining a new design of something like default or base.  If the stock template packages work then you will know the cause of the error is living in your template design files (.phtml).

A lot of templates I've run into are bad about using `Mage::getModel()->load()` within foreach loops as this is [bad practice](http://info.magento.com/rs/magentocommerce/images/Conquer_the_5_Most_Common_Magento_Coding_Issues_to_Optimize_Your_Site_for_Performance.pdf) and can ultimately consume large amounts of server memory and resources.

Magento does have Code Analysis tool that may help scan your template files to determine if there any of these bad pieces of code:

- https://github.com/magento-ecg/magniffer

Further reading:

- [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Also, it may be helpful for everyone what cache and session storage you are using that is defined in `app/etc/local.xml`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: i will try this nad let you know....

Comment: we cleared the var/session folder . than it solved our problem until today. but today this problem again happened. than i added this in .htaccess : SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true" and uncomment ini_set('display_errors', 1); this line. and <disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules> . Than i got tjis error : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94559/fatal-error-class-mage-themeframework-helper-theme-not-found-in-app-mage-php/94561?noredirect=1#comment126660_94561

Comment: i am not clearing any sessin after i do some chnages, if i clear the session automatically its going to solve all the problem. dont you think its something related cookies or sessions ? is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: @BabyinMagento Were you able to get the problem resolved based on the information provided? If so what was the issue for those other experiencing a similar issue? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your support. we cleared the session folder and hide cookie related things in varien.php. but still we need to wait for some more time to check whether we got permanent solution or not. right we got solution as we cleared session folder.

Comment: @Boomer still searching for solution.....

Comment: @BabyinMagento what are using in your `app/etc/local.xml` file for session storage? Also, be sure you are using the full domain path ie, include the `.` at the beginning of your cookie domain name. like: `.totaltoys.com`. This will ensure the cookie can be read across the root and subdomain levels. leaving it empty can cause problems!

Answer (score 3):

My guess is there is a recursion in your code. Edit the file `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php` and set `$_debug` and `$_logCallStack` to true. This should log the call stack in `var/debug/pdo_mysql.log` file which should give you an idea if there is a recursion in your code when it takes forever to load. Note that this file will keep growing very rapidly so ideally enable it when you think the problem has started on site.

Other way is to disable buggy modules/extensions that you think could cause this. This could be your simple configurable prices extension too, try to disable it temporary and see if it helps prevent the issue.

Comment: i changed values of "$_debug" and "$_logCallStack" to true, now i am waiting for pdo_mysql.log file. and our log folders are filling too  much , its almost about 90 gb of logs are there. i installed the simple configurable extension before 2 weeks, this problem was there from 2 months. but still need to look at other buggy modules.

Comment: i didt found this file var/debug/pdo_mysql.log until now, but system and exception logs created. i can see this log mainly : "lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510"

Comment: 90 GB of logs? wow! Backup them to some different place and empty the files. that should atleast help somewhat improve your site speed.

Comment: yes, you are right. we keep on deleting after some times. is those logs because of this issue ? and until now i didt found any pdo_mysql.log

Comment: Check the value of `$_debugFile` in Mysql.php file and make sure your `var` directory has proper permissions required to create a folder and file.

Comment: $debugfile showing 'var/debug/pdo_mysql.log'; this path only. we have 775 permission for var. we will change to 777 and check it.

Comment: we changed var to 777, but still the directory didt created.

Comment: @BabyinMagento Did you ever resolve this?  We've been facing this all year too.

Comment: @ladle3000 no  still i did't found solution  it may be because of 1)modules or poor code 2) or server fault.... may be BOOMER solution may work.....

Comment: So have you just lived with it?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue in a customer website. Check your Magento for malware.

This is a well known scenario, ususally it is a walware redirecting the content of user's post to an external website.

Start checking index.php, they usually hack it. Scroll the code untill the end, also check to the right and between commented lines in the license heading. Hackers are used to hide code in this way.

You have the "forever loading" becasue it tries to contact websites that your ISP blocked.

It should be quite easy to find the malware, search for "base64", "eval", "mcrypt" strings.

Comment: this is our index.php =  > http://pastebin.com/N8xnWMa7

Comment: our site was hacked before 3 months, after that only this problem came. but later we took lot of security measures from server side. but do you think the hacked  code still present in site and creating problem?.

Comment: Well, your index.php is fine, but your symptoms are really like the ones I've seen in some customer hacked webistes. I suggest you to perform a full search looking for the following patterns: "base64", "eval", "mcrypt", "$_POST". They will give you tons of false positives so you need to check them. If you do not find anything wrong I suggest you a cachegrind analysis or an xdebug step-by-step analysis.

Comment: i will search those words in our site files.

Comment: i am finding unlimited times : "base64" encode and decode texts........

Comment: This is quite normal, just check if you have a "strange string" after that, something like "base64_decode('dGhpcyBpcyBhIHRlc3Q=')". Expecyally if base_64decode is within an eval command. Like. eval(base64_decode(....))

Comment: when i quick search entire site files, i found "base64, evel, mcrypt and base64_decode(). but i did't got like eval(base64_decode) but i will search once more.

Comment: This is a good news ;) . Then what I suggest you now is to check the core_sessions table in your MySQL. Also check the "report_*" tables. If you do not find anything you have to do a cachegrind check or and xdebug session.

Answer (score 2):

I have experienced a similar behavior on a Magento that had two websites. The site was loading well for a few pages and then loading forever.

The configuration of the base URLs was wrong. The Secure Base URL setting was set to the wrong website while the Unsecure Base URL was set correctly.

So to fix this if the admin is not even working properly, the values need to be changed in the **core_config_data** table for the right website i.e. set the right URL with the "http://" and a trailing slash in the value field corresponding to the path "web/unsecure/base_url" and "web/secure/base_url" for the right scope_id representing the website ID.

[image]

Note that the secure url is http only because it was a demo website.