# Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Themeframework_Helper_Theme' not found in app/mage.php

Tags: fatal-error

For debugging our site ,  in app/etc/local.xml we set :

```
<disable_local_modules>true</disable_local_modules>
```

but now we are getting this error  :

```
Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Themeframework_Helper_Theme' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547
```

backend is working fine

Comment: have you added any custom extensions?

Comment: yes we have lot of extensions.

Comment: Themeframework extensions available?

Comment: yes, all theme related files are enable

Comment: Themeframework_Helper_Theme file is missing

Comment: app/code/local/EM/Themeframework/Helper/theme.php file is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have disabled the all the local modules. And it seems your local helper is calling from some where in your code and it is giving helper missing error.

Try to search `helper('themeframework/theme')` in all code and see if it is calling from any file other then module itself.

Comment: i will check it

Comment: except theme related files, this line is not present anywhere in the code

Comment: you will need to check it in app/code/community also.

Comment: i checked in complete site code files using ssh using this command : fgrep -r themeframework/theme

Comment: can you check if compilation is on?

Comment: Compiler Status = Disabled, 
Compilation State = Compiled

Comment: we copied the theme and created one dummy theme in site, in that dummy theme i found this :" helper('themeframework/theme')". will it be a problem also? is i have to delete thjat dummy theme ?

Comment: does these theme calling from admin? try to remove that line and check

Comment: i chnaged theme name to default , than this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'keywords' (T_STRING) in app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/html/header.phtml on line 49

Comment: this might be some other issue. need to debug!!!

Comment: we fixed it. now no error in default theme, now chnaged the theme name under "Design" , again same error : Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Themeframework_Helper_Theme' not found in /app/Mage.php on line 547

Comment: it might be issue with system.xml also. check if themeframework module is not using any other system.xml or adminhtml.xml file

Comment: can you please help me how to check themeframework module is not using any other system.xml file

Comment: try to search themeframework in app/code/community and see if you find anything. make sure you still disable local modules

Comment: ya, i am still  using this code :  <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules> in local.xml

Comment: i searched it its coming only from dummy theme files.

Comment: app/design/frontend/default/dummy_theme/template/page/2columns-right.phtml:   

app/design/frontend/default/dummy_theme/template/page/1column.phtml:

Answer (score 1):

If your are disable local module but some places using your module Helper file `$this->helper('themeframework/theme')`

Please find your helper file other module and comment this helper.

Comment: I don' find any difference with my answer!!!

Comment: except theme related files, this line is not present anywhere in the code

Answer (score 1):

You have ***wrongly defined*** the helper `class group name` in `config.xml`  or wrongly call helper call.

You need to check setting at config.xml

```
<global>
  <helpers>
    <themeframework> <!-- this call module helper class group name -->
      <class>EM_Themeframework_Helper</class>
    </themeframework>
  </helpers>
</global>
```

Also `global config file name` should be changed accordingly.

Also check compiler

Comment: same code is present : app/code/local/EM/Themeframework/etc/config.xml

Comment: this is complete config.xml file : http://pastebin.com/hZHBsd6R