# Cookies are killing our site

Tags: session, cookie

This is the problem.

[Live site blank in frontend or keep on loading and never load](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88243/live-site-blank-in-frontend-or-keep-on-loading-and-never-load)

impossible solution is we have to tell to customers that please clear your browser cache and than browse our site.

We need some Permanent solution for this.

please someone help us.

Comment: Why did you open a new question? Why is the bounty not on the original question? My guess is there might be something wrong with the core, did you try to update the store to a newer version so you are sure the Magento core is ok? After that you can look further when needed, but a core problem would be ruled out.

Comment: i tried to create bounty on new question, i should award minimum 300 points, so i created bounty and linked for that. we will try to upgrade to newer version.

Comment: @BabyinMagento instead of wasting days, take fresh copy of magento and install one by one module. if every thing get succeed import the customers, products and orders data. which takes time but its better when we don't have solution

Comment: @prasadmaganti thanks a lot for tips. but client want solution.to fix the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I can see in Chrome Cookies, Magento sets two cookies: one for domain ".sitename.com" and another for "sitename.com" with same name "frontend". After some time cookie with domain "sitename.com" will be expired because Magento does not use it anymore after creation. On all next pages Magento update the cookie with domain ".sitename.com". Probably after expiring you get conflict and it doesn't send any cookie to Magento.
I would recommend you to set Cookie options for your domain like:

Cookie Path: /
Cookie Domain: sitename.com

And check if it still creates two cookies. Also check with domain .sitename.com

Comment: we will check it

Comment: how to test two cookies are created in browser?

Comment: I used Chrome, If you clean cookie and go to the website you will see only one 'frontend' cookie http://screencast.com/t/cOfFxjXXOrbi , further website usage will create one more cookie 'frontend' http://screencast.com/t/Z3Y8aldND0f . After that only second cookie will be used which you can see by non-changing of expired date.

Comment: i followed this : 

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/102283/find-what-cookies-are-creating-in-browser/102286#102286

http://prntscr.com/a4x3ja you can see 2 frontend, means is this the issue, double cookies.

Comment: it didt worked for me

Comment: Two cookies is the reason of having issues on the website. But you will need to figure out what cause this double cookies. Probably some of modules have effect on native functionality. I would recommend you to look for code related to cookies in local and community codepool. Look for usages like: Mage::getModel('core/cookie') or Mage::app()->getCookie(). Also you are interested only in handling cookie "frontend".

Comment: i searched for above 2 lines.... i found here : http://prntscr.com/a7noe1 is those all from default magento right ? we did't found in any other extensions

Answer (score 2):

Other than the suggestion I gave you in the other post (the hacked website possibility) you can also check your core_sessions MySQL table size.

Also check you are not using disk session with a huge session amount.

Make a test changing your local.xml:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

Change to:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

After this flush your cache and see if the problem persists.

Comment: i will check that too.

Comment: it worked when i changed from file to db, again it started giving errors after some time

Comment: Check the number of entriesin core_session table

Comment: i will check that now.....

Comment: only 15 rows are there in table = http://prntscr.com/a79avv

Comment: You have some other WEIRD issue going on there. We should perform a deeper analysis, but start considering a webserver issue

Comment: ys, now our server team is checking the issue, we will let you know soon...

Comment: What was the outcome? @BabyinMagento

Answer (score 1):

Magento has in-built feature of setting the cookies lifetime to any number of seconds.

For turning this feature on go to Admin >> Session Cookie Management >> Lifetime and give a lower value(3600 or lower than that) and "Save" the system-config.

**Hope this works for you**

Comment: we will check it

Comment: it didt worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Several reasons why this could happen.

This happens when a module is trying to initialize a session, before sessions have started, so you may need to debug to find which module is doing that.

The other thing that can help is to set the cookie domain in your configuration as .sitename.com and set path  to /
This is because it mixes www.domain.com and domain.com cookies up.

Lastly, if it's a customer trying to login when the error happens, find that customer and delete the contents of their basket. You may want to think about cleaning out the sales quote tables in the database if this is the issue.

Comment: sure, we will try your solution.....

Comment: i am trying removing one by one module and checking