# Find what cookies are creating in browser

Tags: magento-1.9, session, cookie

we have a domain www.xyz.com 1.9.0 site.

we are facing some problems with cookies.

is magento set 2 types of cookies, one for **xyz.com** and another for **.xyz.com**?

I want to know how to check what cookies are creating for site in browser, we are using chrome, firefox and opera browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are maintained by your web browser, so the method for viewing them will vary depending on which browser you are using. The method for how to view cookies is listed below.

- **Microsoft Internet Explorer 8.0 - 10.0**
  Select the `Tools -> Internet Options` menu item, and then click the `Settings` button under the `General` tab. Click the `View Files` button to see a list of the temporary internet files that Explorer has stored. Cookies have names that begin 'cookie:' - the Internet Address column will tell you which website created the cookie.
  Note - the `Tools` option can also be accessed by clicking the `gear` icon in Internet Explorer's toolbar.
- **Firefox 7.0 and newer**
  Select the `Tools -> Options` menu item (may be under the Firefox button) and click on the `Privacy` tab. Click the `remove individual cookies` link, and you will be shown a list of all cookies stored by Firefox. You can delete selected cookies if you wish, or you can click `Remove All Cookies` to delete them all, or simply browse through the list to see which websites have stored cookies on your computer.
- **Google Chrome**
  Choose `Settings` on the `Customize and control` menu, click `Show advanced settings` at the bottom of the screen. In the `Privacy` section, click on the `Content settings...` button then click the `all cookies and site data` button. You will be shown a list of all websites which have stored cookies on your computer. Selecting a website allows you to see the cookies, and selecting a cookie shows you the data stored in it.
- **Apple Safari 5.1**
  Choose `Preferences...` on the `Settings` or `Edit` menu (Windows) or the Safari menu (MacOS), then open the `Privacy` tab and click the `Details...` button. You will be shown a list of all cookies stored on your computer. Individual cookies can be deleted by selecting them and clicking `Remove` or they can all be deleted by clicking `Remove All`.
- **Apple iOS 5 or later (iPhone, iPad)**
  From the home screen tap the `Settings` icon, then choose `Safari`. Scroll to the bottom of the page and tap `Advanced`. Tap `Website Data` to see a list of cookies.
- **Android**
  Android does not appear to allow users to view individual cookies. You can delete all cookies, or enable/disable them.
- **Windows Phone 7/8**
  Windows Phone does not appear to allow users to view individual cookies. You can delete all cookies, or enable/disable them.
- **Blackberry**
  Blackberry does not appear to allow users to view individual cookies. You can delete all cookies, or enable/disable them.

Note: If you delete or edit cookies on your computer, some websites may require you to re-enter the information which was previously stored in their cookies.

https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647?hl=en

**I hope this will help you.**