# how to set the config cache options to 0 all columns

Tags: cache, https, compilation

we are facing " **No data recieved error in our site** "

[here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/no-data-received-error-in-magento) they gave solution as :

```
1)disable compilation : php -f shel/compiler.php -- disable
2)set the configcacheoptions to 0 all columns
```

I want to know what is mean by

```
set the configcacheoptions to 0 all columns
```

system.log :

```
XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in /var/www/html/site/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510
```

exception.log :

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: ' in /var/www/html/site/app/Mage.php:595
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(495): Mage::throwException('Invalid block t...')
#1 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(437): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_getBlockInstance('', Array)
#2 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('', '')
#3 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('', '')
#4 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#5 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#6 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#7 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#8 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/CatalogSearch/controllers/ResultController.php(77): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout()
#9 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_CatalogSearch_ResultController->indexAction()
#10 /var/www/html/site/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#11 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#12 /var/www/html/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#13 /var/www/html/site/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#14 /var/www/html/site/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#15 {main}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you tell more information when your issue appeared?

Comment: it will appear when we browsing site, it may on product page, checkout or cart page. we are using https for our site, please look at this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/88243/live-site-blank-in-frontend-or-keep-on-loading-and-never-load

Comment: In other words page can be loaded successfully and next time it cannot be loaded?

Comment: you are exactly right,  after deleting cookies than only it will work.

Comment: most probably it's the issue of your virtual server configuration. Please let us know which virtual server do you use? Or if you know how to read error.log - read it and post here last values

Comment: i did't got about virtual server, i updated question with log details

Comment: It looks like you have some issue with one of your blocks. You have added some block without type in one of your layout xml files. Or you did it via CMS admin area

Comment: is there any way to find which block  or layout files?

Comment: Have you modified smth in your app/design folder ? or maybe you created some static blocks in admin area?

Comment: Also we may dig in wrong place!!! Did you look at the date of your error? You have issues on server side (not at magento side). It means that you need to look at server log, not at magento log

Comment: but these are today logs.....

Comment: apache log `child pid 23845 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2`

Comment: It means that you may have more than one issue. I'd recommend to debug from the beginning. Why server issue appear. You need to find your server log. You have an icon in your tray with letter X. Most probably it's yours virtual server. Press right click and find smth which refers to logs or give me the name of this extension.

Comment: I tried to google with this error. Found big article and understand that something strange happen. Most probably this issue doesn't refer to magento and you need to ask this question at some serverfault community. The only thing I can recommend you (I recommend it everybody) don't install magento on Windows. Native system for it is unix. Install virtualbox + ubuntu and enjoy.

Comment: we will check with our server team, but when we cleared session folder, it started to work like charm. do you think still its server issue

Comment: The only think I can say - it's not magento issue

Comment: thanks , i hope so.if that is the case, its going to be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prefer to use n98-magerun https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

By one simple command you can disable/enable/clean cache via console and much much more.

Comment: can you please explain this : `set the config cache options to 0 all columns`

if  we use that github plugin , what i need to do for above line.

Comment: Sorry maybe I didn't understand your question initially. They mean disable cache any way you like. It can be via admin area or via database or somehow you like

Comment: nice, only experts like you can understand those words....